# Performance decline after switching the MySql table engine from innoDB to NDB

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm building a website based on WordPress 4.8. The default table engine is innoDB after going through the installation steps, and everything works fine. While my DBA asked me to change the table engine to NDB, for easy data replication. While after the change, the home pages loads very slowly. After some debugging, I found there are queries take over 10 seconds.

Although I will definitely add some caching mechanism when releasing the website, but I'd like to firstly figure out if there is something we can fix from the DB side, before I adding the cache or optimizing the query. As the query time is 0.4 seconds with innoDB, and my DBA told me NDB should have better performance.

Following is one query that takes 14 seconds for your references, please advice if you have any idea. Thanks!

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS team_football_1001_posts.ID
FROM team_football_1001_posts 
LEFT JOIN team_football_1001_postmeta
ON ( team_football_1001_posts.ID = team_football_1001_postmeta.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN team_football_1001_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( team_football_1001_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN team_football_1001_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( team_football_1001_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN team_football_1001_postmeta AS mt3
ON (team_football_1001_posts.ID = mt3.post_id
AND mt3.meta_key = '_team_winner_id' )
WHERE 1=1 
AND ( team_football_1001_postmeta.meta_key = '_date_start' 
AND ( ( ( mt1.meta_key = '_date_start'
AND mt1.meta_value > '2017-07-07 06:48:49' ) 
OR ( ( mt2.meta_key = '_date_start'
AND mt2.meta_value < '2017-07-07 06:48:49' ) 
AND mt3.post_id IS NULL ) ) ) )
AND team_football_1001_posts.post_type = 'matches'
AND ((team_football_1001_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY team_football_1001_posts.ID
ORDER BY team_football_1001_postmeta.meta_value DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Attached the tables schemas for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `team_football_1001_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2200 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `team_football_1001_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22648 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Start with including the results of the explain and provide what indexes you have onthe affected tables.

Comment: Appended the schema of the two tables that joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to give you bad news after you undoubtedly invested a significant amount of time and capital in moving to NDB, but I would not have recommended using NDB. I would recommend to stay with InnoDB, at least for these tables. This query is never going to take advantage of NDB's strengths.

NDB is not a magical "everything goes fast now" technology. Like every other type of optimization, it improves certain queries—*at the expense of other queries.*

When I worked as a MySQL consultant, it was pretty common to see companies who tried to port their existing application to NDB after being promised that it would have better performance. But you need to design your application, database, and queries specifically to take advantage of NDB's storage architecture from the beginning. Porting any old application to NDB is pretty likely to result in *worse* performance.

I don't think your DBA understood (or else didn't make you understand) how distributed storage works in NDB, and how that affects database design and query design.

Your first table has an auto-increment primary key on `ID`, and your second table has its own auto-increment primary key `meta_id`. NDB spreads data around on its multiple storage nodes based on the modulus of each tables primary key. Since the primary key of your two tables is largely out of sync, every one of your queries has to search for data on all of your storage nodes.

If your primary key for `team_football_1001_postmeta` used the `post_id` as the left-most column, NDB would naturally store related data together on the same storage node. Then the joins you show would always search only one storage node for a given post `ID`.

But actually that won't help, because you're querying for many post `ID`'s. So you're bound to search all the storage nodes anyway.

You're also using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` which often causes a big penalty for performance. But I think the use of NDB with your many-way joins is probably a much worse problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the issue and sharing your experience as well, it is very helpful! I think I will talk to my DBA on the following things: 1. As this is website is purely for the content, no end user interaction, we'd better stick to the innoDB. 2. I'm planning to host the order flow functionality with another WordPress website and DB, we could consider NDB for that instance.

Comment: @hailong, you might want to research the internet to see if anyone else has shared their experience running Wordpress on NDB. It's another database design that was NOT designed with NDB in mind. You should understand that the technology goal of NDB is high availability—not performance.

Comment: Got your point. In my understanding, for the "readonly" website built upon WorkPress, we can guarantee the the high availability with CDN services. In my testing, the WordPress admin console loaded without impact of NDB, so I guess we can still build the website against NDB, but may invest a lot of time to struggle with the optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the data can already change query time (the dbms builds new histogram information and can come to a different execution plan). This is a regular and normal event on which the user has to respond and adjust either indexing or query. To stabilize the situation running regular maintenance is advisable, or sometimes data model changes are required. The goal of the maintenance or the changes is to stabilize the statistical view on the data which is used by the optimizer so that the optimizer always makes the same choice for the execution plan. Oh, often asked: Are there shortcuts? No.